# Is there a way to view the DOM in the debug console of Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm getting a bit annoyed debugging my application in Visual studio code. I'm mid test and wanting to look at the state of the DOM when i'm stopped at a breakpoint.

I can of course put `document.body.innerHTML` in the debug console. However, it prints it out in a pretty ugly way. Not a huge deal, but I get annoyed copying and pasting it all in an html formatter.

It would be great if there was a button or something that prints the whole tree out. Maybe there is and I just don't know about it.
I've tried looking for extensions but didn't see any.

Thanks in advance!